postgreSQL server ver. 14 , how to import dump ( A directory-based archive ) file using pg_restore by remaping schema name
postgreSQL server ver. 14 , how to import dump ( A directory-based archive ) file using pg_restore by remaping schema name?
we need to use pg_dump efficiently with parameter j , as a result we significantly reduced backup time. Then pg_dump output is a directory based achive
the problem is how to remap schema name during restoring.
Oracle solves this problem with remap_schema parameter.
